# Maple 16 Uninstalling Error

Tags: uninstall, maple

Every time I click on the uninstall button, even if I've just rebooted my notebook, 
I get the following error ...

```
Maple 16 currently in use
The uninstaller has detected Maple 16 processes still running.
Please shut them down before proceeding with this uninstallation
```

Of course I'm sure that maple 16 isn't running anywhere on my notebook...
Actually, I think this is a common error on Maple 16 but i didnt found anywhere how to solve it

Comment: Could you add some information? Which OS, which version of maple ect...

Comment: It's Maple 16, I'm using windows 8

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Maple 16 on Windows 8 64-bit machine. Here is my solution:

1. Open file explorer. Locate Maple `unintall.exe` file. It should reside in `"C:\Program Files\Maple 16\unintsall\unintall.exe"`
2. Right click on the file and select Properties.
3. Go to `Compatibility` tab.
4. Select `Windows 7` compatibility mode, then click OK.
5. Now double-click the `uninstall.exe` file.

That should start uninstall procedure without this strange error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on windows 8. Compatibility mode did not help at all. Uninstalling in silent mode worked. Here is how you do it:

UNINSTALLATION

> "C:\Program Files\Maple\uninstall\Uninstall Maple .exe" -f C:\installer.properties

Here the installer.properties file contains the single line
INSTALLER_UI=SILENT

replace "C:\Program Files\Maple\uninstall\Uninstall Maple .exe", with the path to that file on your computer. You need to create the installer.properties file (make sure file extensions are visible in windows!)

I copied the instructions from maplesoft's website:
http://www.maplesoft.com/support/faqs/detail.aspx?sid=32631